# Rearranging Data in an MS Access 2007 table into a new table format/Result Output

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have Access tables that have the following format:

```
--------------------------------------
|Name |Math|Science|Reading|Civics|
--------------------------------------
|Mike | A  |  C    |  A    | B    |
|John | B  |  A    |  A    | B    |
|Randy| A  |  C    |  A    | A    |
|Sasha| B  |  C    |  D    | A    |
|Max  | A  |  C    |  A    | A    |
|Jenn | A  |  A    |  A    | C    |
-----------------------------------
```

Is there any Access Sql code or Access VBA script that I can use so that I can convert (or output in a query/resultset) the above table in the below format?

```
 --------------------
|   Name      |Grade|
---------------------
|Mike Math    | A   |
|Mike Science | c   | 
|Mike Reading | A   |
|Mike Civics  | B   |
|John Math    | B   |
|John Science | A   | 
|John Reading | A   |
|John Civics  | B   |
|Randy Math   | A   |
 etc...
```

What I have found so far are the below 2 threads which shows how to bring in all the field names into an array or just basic output using VBA in Access. It's a start for what I am trying to accomplish (since in essence I will need to bring in the field names into the first column). I'll post back if I'm able to figure it out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548697/how-to-list-fields-name-in-table-in-access-using-sql

http://forums.asp.net/t/1143922.aspx

I'm wondering If I can do something like...

```
For each fieldname in table (where fieldname != Name)
Begin 
select 
Name + ' ' + Subject as Name, 
(select Grade from table where Name = Name and Subject = Subject) as Grade
End
```

Comment: And why are you planning to store 2 different pieces of information (name and subject) in the same column? Why not 3 columns, `name`, `subject`, `grade`?

Comment: Using the example I gave above we don't wan't "Mike", "Mike", "Mike" several times duplicated in "Name" column.
In my actual DB table, the "Name" column is really going to be an Item column (for hotel items) and we can't have duplicate Items. For example we want "Cup-King", "Cup-Queen", "Cup-Junior" instead of "cup", "cup", "cup" in the Item field  with the room type (King, Queen, Junior) in another column.

Comment: You can always concatenate the 2 columns in the output, either in the SQL output or in an application. You don't need though - and you shouldn't - store them in one column.

Comment: @ypercube If I were to go with the 3 column approach as you described (name,subject, grade) do you know of an easy way or of a function I can use either in Excel,Access, or SQL server that will convert my table to (name,subject,grade) format? I guess I just need to be able to read the field/column name into the output result.

Comment: and add some loopty loops....

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and clarify: Do all the tables have the same exact format (number of columns and names of columns)? Should the answer be for Access or SQL-Server?

Comment: @ypercube Done. The answer should be for Access. When I mentioned SQL in the original question I meant SQL code in an Access query (SQL view) or VBA solution. All my tables do not have the same number of columns or names but If I can figure out how to convert 1 table (above example) to the new format, I will be able to continue from there (even if i have to modify the code to work for the other tables). Thanks!

Comment: How many tables do you have? You could write the queries by hand if there's just a few.

Comment: Otherwise does TRANSFORM help you?

Comment: @Colin'tHart I have close to 50 tables So I will need to find a solution that I can apply to all the other tables (even if I have to run the solution once for each table). If I can find a way to convert/output the data in my example above into the new format, then I can go from there. I am reading into the TRANSFORM command you mentioned. It might be just what I need. I'll post back. Thanks!

Comment: I don't pivot/unpivot very often and each time I have to read the documentation and examples thoroughly to determine what I want. Good luck! If TRANSFORM doesn't work, it can be done with plain SQL specially written for each case, but those statements could be generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT [Name] & " Math" AS col1, tab1.Math FROM tab1
UNION ALL
SELECT [Name] & " Science" AS col1, tab1.Science FROM tab1
UNION ALL
SELECT [Name] & " Reading" AS col1, tab1.Reading FROM tab1
UNION ALL
SELECT [Name] & " Civics" AS col1, tab1.Civics FROM tab1
Order BY 1;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Works Great! Since I have about 50 tables I'm going to try to have a vba or sql script output the code for me for all the different tables by bringing the column names (since they are different) but the code you have provided me will save me A TON of TIME! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a button in a form and paste the below code

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim tbl As TableDef
Set db = CurrentDb
For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
    If tbl.Name = "Result" Then
    db.Execute "DROP TABLE Result"
    Else
    End If
Next tbl

db.Execute "CREATE TABLE Result(Names varchar(100),Grade varchar(10))"

Set db = CurrentDb

rst.Open "Tab1", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic

Dim n As Integer
Dim fieldname As String
Dim str As String

For n = 1 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    fieldname = rst.Fields(n).Name
    str = "Insert Into Result ([Names],Grade) SELECT [Name] & " & Chr(34) & " " & fieldname & Chr(34) & " As Names," & "tab1." & fieldname & " As Grade FROM tab1;"

    db.Execute str


Next n

End Sub
```

No Matter how many number of fields available, this code will work fine.
I have taken help of cha's UNION ALL Query and developed the code. 
The results will be stored in a new table created by name "Result".

Comment: Thank you! I had already used the previous answer to convert my tables but I was able to use your code to Union all 50 tables without having to write out all the code manually! Save me a lot of time! Thankas again!